# Office 365 Groups - Create Default OneNote Document

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We're creating Office 365 Groups using a PowerShell script, and this process in place already and we're happy with it.

I was wondering however, if it was possible to trigger the creation of the default OneNote document via the Graph API at all? It appears as though when a Group is created, it's not until someone manually visits the Document library and clicks the OneNote document, is it actually created (on the fly). I have arrived at this conclusion because if we run a `Get-UnifiedGroup` on the group itself (storing the result in `$Group`), the following property is empty: `$Group.SharePointNotebookUrl`

The reason we'd like to do this, is so we can create Office 365 Groups and populate the default OneNote notebook with some information, without having to have a user with permission to the group, manually trigger the creation of it. I'm able to create additional notebooks in the Group, but these are not 'presented' in the same way to end users that the default one is (with it's own dedicated tabs/menu links).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible from Microsoft Graph today. As you noted, the default OneNote for a Group is created the first time you attempt to access it. It's also a little different in that it gets places in a SiteAssetts library which *also* doesn't exist when the group is created.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this as a suggestion.

Comment: I also spent a few hours going down a rabbit hole to see if I could replicate the automated process. Most of what I attempted either failed outright or resulted in breaking things in odd ways. Just wanted to make sure that if you were considering this path, you can't stop considering. :)

Comment: Thanks for digging Marc. Just to confirm, this still appears to be the case at the time of writing (sadly).

Comment: even if you do something like sending an email to the user to say "go click that link" and have periodic polling of the data, for some reason it takes the Graph/OneNote API "time" to realize there is now a default notebook available… This is far from ideal

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 default Notebook is a file in SiteAssets library in the associated SharePoint site.

If Notebook is not created yet, you can create by enabling SharePoint Feature `SiteNotebook` with Id `f151bb39-7c3b-414f-bb36-6bf18872052f`

**With PnP PowerShell:**

```bsh
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity f151bb39-7c3b-414f-bb36-6bf18872052f -Scope Web
```

This will create Notebook in SiteAssets library and adds `PropertyBag` to `SPWeb` with name "SiteNotebookGuid".